# Text box and Drop Down list

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net

I want design a web form,its have to control one Text Box and one Drop Down list when type a number between 5 and 10 in Text Box, Drop Down list is include 1,2,3,4,5 and when type a number between 11 and 20 in Text Box, Drop Down list is include 6,7,8,9,10.

How to do it without page refreshing?

please explain with code.

Comment: can you share with us the code that you currently use?

Comment: `"how to do it without page refreshing?"` - By writing code in JavaScript.  Break the problem apart into discrete components.  For example: 1) Responding to the text changing in an `input`. 2) Restricting an `input` to numeric text. 3) Reading the text from an `input`. 4) Parsing that numeric text to a number. 5) Executing your logic. 6) Changing the options in a `select`. etc.  Each discrete step is easily Googled and there are many examples.  Start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code may help you.

```
 <select id="txt" onchange="changeNumber()">
   <option>select value</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
</select>
<script>
function changeNumber(){
    var t_value=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    if(t_value==10 ||t_value==11 || t_value==12 || t_value==13 || t_value==14 || t_value==15 ){
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var j=1
        for(var i=0;i<=y.options.length;i++){
            y[i].text=j;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In this way you can solve your 2nd problem.

Comment: @ shiva : I am not getting you.

Comment: I mean, this was not i want if insert digit in text box between 10 and 20 then options in drop down are 1,2,3,4 else if digit between 20 and 30 options in drop down are 5,6,7,8 without refreshing and button

Comment: No :( i want a text box when insert in text box digit between 1 to 10(for Example insert 1 or 2 or 3 or... 10 ) then items in drop down list are 1,2,3,4 and then insert digit in text box between 11 to 20, items in drop down list are 5,6,7,8

Comment: @ shiva : first tell me how the action/event will execute.you need user  insert value(i.e.1----10) then in the drop downlist the value will be set in beetween 1-5 and you dont need any page refresh.

Comment: :) yes Exactly i want this

Comment: @ shiva :Let me to explain my posted code.When user will select any value from first drop downlist according the desired values will set in second drop down list.If you dont need this way you can follow my first way which had a text box to insert the input value.Meaning is same but you need to fire the event.

Comment: @ shiva :check my second answer and run this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow the below code.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="checkValue();" />
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
</select>
<script>
function checkValue(){
    var t_value=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    if(t_value==10 ||t_value==11 || t_value==12 || t_value==13 || t_value==14 || t_value==15){
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var j=1
        for(var i=0;i<=y.options.length;i++){
            y[i].text=j;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I think this type of solution you need.

Comment: Ok it good but when type 2 in text box ,option don't change in drop down! For example it's change and include 5,6,7,8

Comment: @ shiva : I have shown you the way,you have to put the condition as per you requirement.